# How to make array into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

im sorry my english so bad[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUYB.png) I have form input and array[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgbZ8.png) How i make array into varible so i can show into my view blade template like this
Wearpack : 20000
Laoudry  : 20000
Thanks

Comment: are you asking how to assign an array to a variable ...?

Comment: you can retrive data like this : $array_name["input_name"]

Answer (score 0):

If you can post your problem in full description then we can able to solve your problem If you want to store some value of array in varibale. Here is example:-

```
$array = array('name' =>'abc' ,'age' => '20');
```

Now if you want to save name in variable do like this:-

```
$name = $array['name'];
$age = $array['age'];
```

Hope it will helps you

Comment: Meh... `extract($array);`

Comment: Yes. Your answer is more suited as an comment. Extracting arrays is unnecessary. If you do it anyways then at least use extract and not grabbing them one by one.The question itself should be deleted in my opinion. It has pictures for code, poor description, no efforts, I bet when he typed the title there was a few suggested threads with the answer right there in front of his face.

Comment: if helping someone and getting downvote for that  Thank you @Andreas

Comment: Sure. I'm happy to help.

Comment: @Andreas you are not helping you downvoting someone answer and if you have good solution post your answer

Comment: No, I will not answer such a low quality question that lacks effort, googling and even a quick glance in the manual. Be happy that you got 8 points on this. If you don't like it you have two options. Report it to mods and they will most likely delete the question and you will loose the 8 points too. Or post in meta. I bet everyone who agrees with me will downvote your answer. Your answer is not that great. Yes you may have helped OP, but it's actually a poor answer. There is no need to extract arrays, it usually just messes stuff up. Your answer is very generic this not really aimed at OP.

Comment: So may reasons to downvote in my opinion. None to upvote. It's up to you now. But I advice you to be happy with the 8 points.